# PyCharm Tkintertoy won't import

Tags: python, package, pycharm

I run this code:

```py
from tkintertoy import Window
gui = Window()
gui.setTitle('My First Tkintertoy GUI!')
gui.addEntry('name', 'Type in your name')
gui.addLabel('welcome', 'Welcome message')
gui.addButton('commands')
gui.plotxy('name', 0, 0)
gui.plotxy('welcome', 0, 1)
gui.plotxy('commands', 0, 2, pady=10)
while True:
    gui.waitforUser(    )
    if gui.content:
        gui.set('welcome', 'Welcome ' + gui.get('name'))
    else:
        break
```

And I get the returning message:

```
C:\Users\maitken\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\maitken\Documents\tkintertoy.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\maitken\Documents\tkintertoy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tkintertoy import Window
  File "C:\Users\maitken\Documents\tkintertoy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tkintertoy import Window
ImportError: cannot import name Window

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm trying to run the code from the developers of tkinkertoy, but am new to using PyCharm and so don't understand how to import packages. I was expecting this code to produce a pop up window.

Comment: Ensure that the tkintertoy module is installed in the same environment where you are running your script. Also, make sure there are no naming conflicts with your script file named tkintertoy.py, which might be causing the issue.